# Dividing and Multiplying in views - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In the following html template, I am trying to get the percentage, in the form:

**4%**

but when I perform multiplication and division, it appears as

**2/50*100**

How can I get my desired result?

```
<div class="card-content collapse show">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      @foreach ($items->products as $i)
       <div style="font-size:14px">{{$i->count}}/{{$total}}*100 %</div>
                      @endforeach 
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I'm not a laravel expert but at a guess you do you need to preface the calculation code with an `@`, just like your other code blocks? I would think the `{{...}}` syntax is maybe just for quick display of a variable? Therefore it's printing those variable values inside the brackets, just like you asked it to, and treating the rest of it as static text rather than PHP code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must do the calculation inside the brackets:

```
{{ number_format($i->count / $total * 100, 2) }}%
```