# how to calculate on Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I want to calculate something in blade.

I want 2 value divide in [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) view blade

I want $line['product_custom_fields'] divided by $line['quantity']

```php
@forelse($receipt_details->lines as $line) @endif
                
<td class="text-center" style="border: 1px solid black;">{{$line['quantity']}}</td>
<td class="text-center" style="border: 1px solid black;"></td>
<td class="text-center" name="free2" style="border: 1px solid black;">{{$line['product_custom_fields']}}</td>
```

[image: this is what i want]

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dividing and Multiplying in views - laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51361132/dividing-and-multiplying-in-views-laravel)

Comment: @Unflux this is not the answer i want

Comment: It might not be an exact match for your scenario but it shows how to perform division in a blade view, which is what you're trying to do.